# How to display timestamps in table

Tags: oracle, timestamp, settings

I need help. is there a setting to allow the display of timestamps in tables?
the database is part of my job however a senior analyst of mine queried the same code and his managed to show the timestamps next to the date, mine doesnt. he told me there is a setting and asked me to search on my own.

I am using Version 4.1.2.20 of Oracle SQL Developer Build MAIN-20.64

Here is the table

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a 'setting'. If you want to get data from a table you specify what you want as part of a query.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - The question is not about getting the data, it is about displaying it. "Settings" is exactly what controls how data is displayed. In this case, they are some of the "NLS settings", and/or whatever settings the GUI has, which in some unfortunate cases completely ignore the NLS settings.

Comment: correct! appreciate the help mathguy!

Answer (score 1):

Some GUI have their own settings for things like timestamp formats, and they ignore your NLS settings. (I find that quite annoying. Toad does that, among others.)

SQL Developer is good: it has such settings (you can hunt them down and use them), but you can also change them with standard SQL statements. What you need is something like

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff6';
```

(assuming you need six decimal places for the second, and the format model is the one you need). Use whatever format you require; but only fools (including, alas, Oracle itself!) use two-digit numbers for the year.

Something to pay attention to though: what is the data type of column `created_dt`? If it is `date`, for example, you will need to change `nls_date_format` (which doesn't take decimals for seconds); if it's `timestamp with time zone` then you will need to give a format including time zone elements, and you will need to change `nls_timezone_tz_format`.

You can also find these settings (and change them directly there - the valid formats are the same) in SQL Developer under

```
>> Tools >> Preferences >> Database >> NLS
```